# Layout folders not showing layouts.xml files after updating Android Studio 3.2

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle

I've implemented multiple layout folders to divide the xml files for the project.& implemented it as below:

**build.gradle(app)**

```
android{
    sourceSets{
        main{
            java{
                res.srcDirs = [
                'src/main/res/layouts/activities',
                'src/main/res/layouts/cards',
                'src/main/res/layouts/views',
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it was working perfectly fine until I updated Android Studio to 3.2.
So, is there any another way to implement this functionality?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug in new update android studio 3.2
Step:1 change version and dependency like compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion
--->compileSdkVersion 27

---> targetSdkVersion 27

and then

---> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' to

---> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
Step 2 :create new activity  .it automatically appear layout floder